# VBA editor in any Office 365 app not opening anymore

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, crash, office365

I am using VBA in most of my office 365 applications for many years now. Last week an error appeared that I can't fix anymore, without having to create a new profile in windows (according to Microsoft helpdesk). Besides that this is quiet a lot of work that I would like to avoid, if this is the only solution, I like to know what happened and why, to prevent future errors.

**Problem**: in **any** office 365 application, when opening the vba editor, in the taskbar, a window appears that I cannot open and that looks like a corrupted editor window. Hence I cannot edit my code anymore. The code is runnable though from the developers-macros-run-menu.

**Cause**: I ran a code from ms-word, that saves the pages from a merged document into separte files, .docx and .pdf. The code was running fine, but after a little editing started to quit before the last page was reached and after some time trying over, I couldn't open the editor anymore. I am not sure if this error is caused by the code, or something else.
Unfortunately I cannot display the code here, because I can't open it anymore.

I updated Office 365 to the last version, without any result. 
Creating a new Windows-account solves the problem, but implies that I have to reinstall many apps and services.

Does anyone have had the same experience, what is the problem and/ or what can I do to restore this error other than the new-account solution?

Comment: Sounds like the window is opening off-screen. See [this thread on SU](https://superuser.com/q/53585/851686) for solutions if that's the issue. If it's not, please provide further details (such as how it looks on the taskbar)

Comment: Did you try *repairing* the Office installation? Uinstall and re-install? Restart Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VBA Editor window moved off screen. This might have been caused by accidentally pressing WINDOWS KEY + SHIFT + ARROW (not likely), or by a problem in windows 10.

For a solution see https://superuser.com/q/53585

Answer (score 0):

I'd the same problem.

That´s just a question of hidden windows. Just press shift and left click on top of the code window in the task bar. Then select maximze and your window will appear.

Hope it helps.
Joao